# Как изменить href="" через PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть ссылки формата:
`href="/images/virtuemart/product/resized/img-01_1200x0.jpg"`
`href="/images/virtuemart/product/resized/img-02_1200x0.jpg"`
`href="/images/virtuemart/product/resized/img-03_1200x0.jpg"` и так далее.
Как убрать для ссылок `<a href="" class="cropped">` из URL обрезалось `resized/` и `_1200x0` и оставалось, на примере первой ссылки вот так: `href="/images/virtuemart/product/img-01.jpg"`

Comment: [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '
    <a href="/images/virtuemart/product/resized/img-01_1200x0.jpg" class="cropped">1</a>
    <a href="/images/virtuemart/product/resized/img-02_1200x0.jpg" class="foo">2</a>
    <a href="/images/virtuemart/product/resized/img-03_1200x0.jpg" class="cropped">3</a>
';

$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '~<a href="[^"]+" class="cropped"~',
    function($m){
        return preg_replace(['~resized/~', '~_[^.]+~'], '', $m[0]);
    },
    $str
);

var_dump($str);
```

---

Результат:

```
<a href="/images/virtuemart/product/img-01.jpg" class="cropped">1</a>
<a href="/images/virtuemart/product/resized/img-02_1200x0.jpg" class="foo">2</a>
<a href="/images/virtuemart/product/img-03.jpg" class="cropped">3</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если необходимо использовать именно `<a href="..."/>` таким образом, чтобы он не выполнялся `html` разметкой, то можем использовать `htmlspecialchars`.

Вот пример без использования регулярных выражений:

```php
<?php
$str = '<a href="/images/virtuemart/product/resized/img-01_1200x0.jpg"/>';
$str1 = '<a href="/images/virtuemart/product/resized/img-02_1200x0.jpg"/>';
$str2 = '<a href="/images/virtuemart/product/resized/img-03_1200x0.jpg"/>';


function newUrl($val){
    $val = str_replace('/resized', '', $val);
    $temp = explode('_', $val);
    $temp1 = explode('.', $temp[1]);
    $val = $temp[0].$temp1[1];
    return $val;
}

print_r(newUrl(htmlspecialchars($str)));
print_r(newUrl(htmlspecialchars($str1)));
print_r(newUrl(htmlspecialchars($str2)));
```

результат:

```
<a href="/images/virtuemart/product/img-01.jpg"/>
<a href="/images/virtuemart/product/img-02.jpg"/>
<a href="/images/virtuemart/product/img-03.jpg"/>
```

Для обработки данных без тегов `<a>` или без `href` тоже можно использовать данную функцию.